# Quit application and execute false boolean after if statement

Tags: javascript

I am working on Colt Steele Web Dev Bootcamp exercises and running into a issue I don't understand. When I hit "quit" or "q", the application should quit. However, you have to enter "quit" or "q" twice in order for the application to result to false. User should only have to type quit once.
updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/bGqrXvw)

```
let input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');
const todos = ['Groceries', 'Laundry'];
let appStart = true;
while (appStart) {
    if (input === 'list') {
        for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
            console.log(`${i}: ${todos[i]}`);
        }
    } else if (input === 'new') {
        const newTodo = prompt('Enter new todo');
        todos.push(newTodo);
        console.log(`${newTodo} added to the list.`);
    } else if (input === 'delete') {
        const index = parseInt(prompt('Enter index to delete.'));
        if (!Number.isNaN(index)) {
            const deleted = todos.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(`${deleted[0]} was deleted from your todo list.`);
        } else {
            console.log('Unknown index.');
        }
    } else if (input === 'quit' || input === 'q') {
        // console.log('You quit the app.');
        appStart = false;
    }
    input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');
}
```

Comment: Your `while` condition isn't checked again until *after* the `input = prompt`.

Comment: @stephen, both of the answers provided resolve your issue, please mark as `resolved`  , and good luck!

Comment: @StarshipladDev There is no way to mark a question as resolved. A poster can chose to accept an answer if it helps them, or they may chose not to accept any answer, and that's okay. Since you have an answer on this question, the best way of reminding askers of their options may be to point them to [the help center article on what to do when someone answers their question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @HereticMonkey too much time on JIRA I suppose x'D

Comment: @HereticMonkey I get what StarshipladDev meant. No biggie.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand. Keep fighting the crime!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for `input` (which will be false if someone clicks `cancel`) AND `appStart` before presenting another popup.

```js
let input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');
const todos = ['Groceries', 'Laundry'];
let appStart = true;
while (appStart) {
  if (input === 'list') {
    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      console.log(`${i}: ${todos[i]}`);
    }
  } else if (input === 'new') {
    const newTodo = prompt('Enter new todo');
    todos.push(newTodo);
    console.log(`${newTodo} added to the list.`);
  } else if (input === 'delete') {
    const index = parseInt(prompt('Enter index to delete.'));
    if (!Number.isNaN(index)) {
      const deleted = todos.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(`${deleted[0]} was deleted from your todo list.`);
    } else {
      console.log('Unknown index.');
    }
  } else if (input === 'quit' || input === 'q') {
    // console.log('You quit the app.');
    appStart = false;
  }
  if (input && appStart) input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running through a loop based on `appStart`. However, if `appStart` is set to false in the loop, at the bottom a prompt still runs regardless of how `appStart` has been changed within the loop. Therefore, a prompt will always appear a second time until the loops condition is checked again.

At the bottom of the method, put a check for `appStart` around `input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');` like so:

```
else if (input === 'quit' || input === 'q') {
        // console.log('You quit the app.');
        appStart = false;
    }
    if(appStart && input){
      //As per @Kinglish, `input` needs to be checked to make sure they didn't press 'cancel
      input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the user clicking 'cancel'. If they do, it will keep prompting them.

Comment: @Kinglish right you are, I really assumed 'cancel' would override any user commands, it just seems like common sense UI design!
That's good to know for the future

Comment: @Kinglish I have stolen your `if (input && appStart) input = prompt('Enter new, delete, or list.');` code snippet and you accordingly in my answer